# Adding excluded files to publish

Tags: solution-package

I am working on a SharePoint project using VS2019.

When I publish the project, I need to add additional some files to the `wsp` file. These files are excluded from the project.

I have been looking at the `Package.package` thing, but without luck so far.

I tried to add the following to the manifest without success:

```
<TemplateFiles>
 <TemplateFile Location="Layouts\Angular\*"/>
</TemplateFiles>
```

I have been looking at the following resources in an attempt to make progress:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/merging-xml-in-feature-and-package-manifests?view=vs-2019
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/how-to-add-and-remove-additional-assemblies?view=vs-2019
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/how-to-create-a-sharepoint-solution-package-by-using-msbuild-tasks?view=vs-2019

I get a feeling I may have to use `msbuild`, but I have not worked with it before. Perhaps someone can confirm that it is the only way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out the Package file did not matter. It needed to be solved using `msbuild`.

It was practically impossible to figure out how to get my hands on `msbuild`, as it seems heavily embedded into Visual studio nowadays...

`Tools -> Command Lines -> Developer PowerShell`

Bam, you now have `msbuild`!

My problem was, that I needed to include some generated files, but touching the `*.csproj` file was not viable as Visual Studio regularly would override my changes...

`*.targets` files to the rescue!

I created the following file (`CustomBuildProcess.targets`) at the root of my project:

```xml
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>  
        <Content Include="Layouts\Angular\**\*" Importance="High"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And imported it in the `*.csproj` file as so:

`<Import Project="$(ProjectDir)\CustomBuildProcess.targets" />`

I just dumped the above line next to another Import line - specifically this one:

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`

After making these small changes, running the following command from the developer powershell was all the magic I needed:

`$ msbuild [*.csproj] /t:Package`

And now my Angular files are included in the `*.wsp` file while still being "excluded" in Visual Studio.

Lastly, a huge shout out to this wordpress website I found after roughly 10 hours of googling: https://chrisa.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/customising-your-build-process/